# Identifying whether a certificate is der encoded or base 64 encoded

Tags: security, encoding, base64, certificate, x509

Is there a way by which I can know the encoding type of a certicate file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if the certificate file I have is in .pem format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215771/how-can-i-check-if-the-certificate-file-i-have-is-in-pem-format)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you open the certificate up in notepad and it starts with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- then it's Base64 encoded. if it's all goobledygook it's DER encoded.

Comment: And when you've got the wrong one! PEM to DER:
`openssl x509 -in cert.crt -outform der -out cert.der` DER to PEM:
`openssl x509 -in cert.crt -inform der -outform pem -out cert.pem`

Answer (score 1):

Informational since this got a search hit - All X.509 certs pretty much use Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER) as the defacto encoding standard to store certificate data in Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1).  Base64 is a form of  binary-to-text encoding (usually in ASCII text).  This makes it "transmission" friendly.

Ref:
http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/Certificate-Format-DER-Distinguished-Encoding-Rules.html

https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them