# Reading a ASN.1 DER-encoded RSA Public key

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, asn.1

I'm writing an app to get a better understanding of DKIM.  The spec says I retrieve a "ASN.1 DER-encoded" public key from the domain TXT record.  I can seen the key on "s1024._domainkey.yahoo.com" = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDrEee0Ri4Juz+QfiWYui/E9UGSXau/2P8LjnTD8V4Unn+2FAZVGE3kL23bzeoULYv4PeleB3gfm".

How can I use this key from .net?  The examples I've seen get the key from a X509Certificate2, or an XML file containing the RSAParameters.

**CORRECTION**: I copy/pasted the key above from the network-tools.com DNS tool, which must've cut it short.  nslookup gives me the full key:

> s1024._domainkey.yahoo.com      text =
>   "k=rsa; t=y; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDrEee0Ri4Juz+QfiWYui/E9UGSXau2P8LjnTD8V4Unn+2FAZVGE3kL23bzeoULYv4PeleB3gfm"
>   "JiDJOKU3Ns5L4KJAUUHjFwDebt0NP+sBK0VKeTATL2Yr/S3bTxhy+1xtj4RkdV7fVxTn56Lb4udUnwuxK4V5b5PdOKj+XcwIDAQAB; n=A 1024 bit key;"

So abelenky was on the right track with BASE64..

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30074/22709 and https://web.archive.org/web/20120124211352/http://blog.oddbit.com/2011/05/converting-openssh-public-keys.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the base64-encoding of the DER-encoding of an ASN.1 PublicKeyInfo containing an RSA public key.

Here is a translation:

```
   0 30  159: SEQUENCE {
   3 30   13:   SEQUENCE {
   5 06    9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER '1 2 840 113549 1 1 1'
  16 05    0:     NULL
            :     }
  18 03  141:   BIT STRING 0 unused bits, encapsulates {
  22 30  137:       SEQUENCE {
  25 02  129:         INTEGER
            :           00 EB 11 E7 B4 46 2E 09 BB 3F 90 7E 25 98 BA 2F
            :           C4 F5 41 92 5D AB BF D8 FF 0B 8E 74 C3 F1 5E 14
            :           9E 7F B6 14 06 55 18 4D E4 2F 6D DB CD EA 14 2D
            :           8B F8 3D E9 5E 07 78 1F 98 98 83 24 E2 94 DC DB
            :           39 2F 82 89 01 45 07 8C 5C 03 79 BB 74 34 FF AC
            :           04 AD 15 29 E4 C0 4C BD 98 AF F4 B7 6D 3F F1 87
            :           2F B5 C6 D8 F8 46 47 55 ED F5 71 4E 7E 7A 2D BE
            :           2E 75 49 F0 BB 12 B8 57 96 F9 3D D3 8A 8F FF 97
            :           73
 157 02    3:         INTEGER 65537
            :         }
            :       }
            :   }
```

The OBJECT IDENTIFIER indicates that the following BIT STRING contains the encoding of an RSAPublicKey. The INTEGERs are the modulus and the public exponent.

You can decode the base64 with [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx), but I don't think .NET has built-in functionality for parsing PublicKeyInfos, so you need to use a 3rd party tool like BouncyCastle.

Comment: the key was cut short.. i've updated the question with the full key.  this does make a lot more sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone interested in this matter I would suggest the **[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.publickey.aspx)** which can be used to read a DER encoded public key.

Answer (score 2):

That string looks like its some sort of base-64 encoding.
If you convert that string from base-64 to a BLOB, it should then be in valid ASN.1 format.

Comment: I've tried converting it from BASE64 - no luck.  This post suggests DER-encoded is something similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657989/identifying-whether-a-certificate-is-der-encoded-or-base-64-encoded

Answer (score 1):

Try the [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) library, it provides great functionality for such cases.