# How can I check if the certificate file I have is in .pem format?

Tags: security, certificate

I have a root cert file and I don't know whether or not it is in `.pem` format. How do I check if it is in `.pem` format?

Comment: Related post - [Identifying whether a certificate is der encoded or base 64 encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/657989/465053)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A .pem format certificate will most likely be ASCII-readable. It will have a line `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, followed by base64-encoded data, followed by a line `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`. There may be other lines before or after.

Answer (score 82):

[DER vs. CRT vs. CER vs. PEM Certificates and How To Convert Them](https://support.ssl.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19)

Quote from the support page:

```
View
====

Even though PEM encoded certificates are ASCII they are not human
readable.  Here are some commands that will let you output the
contents of a certificate in human readable form;

View PEM encoded certificate
----------------------------

Use the command that has the extension of your certificate replacing
cert.xxx with the name of your certificate

openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text -noout
openssl x509 -in cert.cer -text -noout
openssl x509 -in cert.crt -text -noout

If you get the folowing error it means that you are trying to view a DER encoded certifciate and need to use the commands in the “View DER encoded certificate 
below”

unable to load certificate
12626:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:647:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE View DER encoded Certificate


View DER encoded Certificate
----------------------------

openssl x509 -in certificate.der -inform der -text -noout

If you get the following error it means that you are trying to view a PEM encoded certificate with a command meant for DER encoded certs. Use a command in the “View PEM encoded certificate above

unable to load certificate
13978:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1306:
13978:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:380:Type=X509
```

Comment: I was working with a file with .cer extension but the file was in .der format your answer solve my problem.

Comment: My cert file said "unable to load certificate" when I tried to read both types.

Answer (score 44):

Reference [CRL,CRT,CSR,NEW CSR,PRIVATE KEY, PUBLIC KEY Parser](https://8gwifi.org/PemParserFunctions.jsp)

CRL

```
-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----
-----END X509 CRL-----
```

CRT

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

CSR

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

NEW CSR

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

PEM

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

PKCS7

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
-----END PKCS7-----
```

PRIVATE KEY

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: A CRT file extension doesn't specify the encoding. It can hold a binary DER or base64 PEM encoded certificate.

Answer (score 8):

For OpenSSL to recognize it as a PEM format, it must be encoded in Base64, with the following header :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

and footer :

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Also, each line must be maximum 79 characters long.  Otherwise you will receive the error :

```
2675996:error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode:pem_lib.c:818:
```

Note : the PEM standard (RFC1421) mandates lines with 64 characters long. A PEM certificate stored as a single line can be converted with the UNIX command-line utility

```
fold -w 64
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick way to determine the type of a file on Linux is to use the `file` command. Example against a file containing PEM encoded private key:

```
file mypemfile
```

Output:

```
mypemfile: PEM RSA private key
```

Example against an OpenSSH file containing a private key:

```
file id_rsa
```

Output:

```
id_rsa: OpenSSH private key
```

Example against an OpenSSH file containing a public key:

```
file id_rsa.pub
```

Output:

```
id_rsa.pub: OpenSSH RSA public key
```

And finally an example not related to SSL to show how versatile the file command is:

```
file myimage.png
```

Output:

```
myimage.png: PNG image data, 671 x 169, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

It should be noted that the file command does not depend on the file extension. It checks out the file [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) or probably parses the content of the file to determine the nature of the content.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the way you formatted the question, I believe there is some confusion on what a `.pem` file is. The `.pem` part of a file is just the file extension, and I believe that what you actually want to know is how to tell if a file is PEM-*encoded*. A PEM-encoded file can show up in many file formats, such as `.pem`, `.key`, `.cer`, `.cert`, as well as others.

A simple way to check if a certificate is PEM-encoded is to use [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/):

```
openssl x509 -noout -in input_file.pem
echo $?
> 0
```

As an example, the above command will fail for certificates that are in DER format instead of PEM and output an error:

```
139836630553024:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check if the certificate file I have is in .pem format

`cat` the file and look for the pre-encapsulated header and post-encapsulated header. The pre-encapsulated header is `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` or `-----BEGIN X509 CERTIFICATE-----`; and the post-encapsulated header is `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` or `-----END X509 CERTIFICATE-----`.

Encapsulated headers are discussed in [RFC 1421](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1421.txt). There is no standard list or comprehensive list of the objects in those headers (like `CERTIFICATE` or `X509 CERTIFICATE`). Most folks use OpenSSL's `pem.h` header for a list of object types.