# FTP TLS/SSL self signed .cert file "object not found"

Tags: c#, ssl, ftp, certificate

I´m trying to connect to my FTP Server and upload a simple Test .txt file to the server. But I got the following exception: "The requested object was not found." My Certificate is created with FileZilla and have the extension .cert and not .crt.

It´s the latest FileZilla server which is running on Windows 10. I have already tried to generate a new certificate or load my certificate. I also googled a lot, but nothing helped me.

```cs
                request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format(@"ftp://{0}/{1}/{2}", stringIP, "Test", absoluteFileName))) as FtpWebRequest;
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(stringUsername, stringPassword);
                request.EnableSsl = true;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
                X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Properties.Settings.Default.setting_CertPath);
                X509CertificateCollection certCollection = new X509CertificateCollection();
                certCollection.Add(cert);
```

I except that the .txt file is uploaded to my FTP Server successfully. But at the moment it´s running in an exception.

Comment: Stupid question, but does the file specified in `Properties.Settings.Default.setting_CertPath` exist?

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti Yeah, f the application is starting you select the file via OpenFileDialog.

Comment: It looks like your cert file format is not supported, make sure it is ASN.1 DER.

Comment: @muaz But it´s original from FileZilla Server created, but how can I make sure that it´s ASN?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215771/how-can-i-check-if-the-certificate-file-i-have-is-in-pem-format) ,in general if it can be edited via text editor then it is in PEM format, and also see this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.createfromcertfile?view=netframework-4.8) documentation remarks about CreateFromCertFile method.