# C# x509 certificate decoder

Tags: c#, cryptography, decode, x509

I'm looking for a C# code how to decode x509 certificate from string like in this page: https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html

I have a certificate string, that starts with MII... and ends with == .

When I past it in https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html  it works but I want to have my own tool like this site.

Any help?

Comment: X509Certificate2 class can help as it has the properties and methods you need.

Comment: Related post - [Identifying whether a certificate is der encoded or base 64 encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/657989/465053)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I have a certificate string, that starts with MII... and ends with ==

it is a Base64 formatting of the ASN.1 DER encoded certificate. You can convert this string to a byte array and then construct an instance of `X509Certificate2` class:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("MII<...>==");
var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
```

For further reading:

[Convert.FromBase64String Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx)

[X509Certificate2 Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx)